# Does the wrist have more neurons than the finger?

Tags: neuroscience, sensation, pain

Once upon a time, I felt an ant crawling on my hand. I couldn't feel it initially, until it reached my wrist. Then I tried to let the ant crawl on my skin; what I found was that I couldn't feel the ant when it crawled on my finger tips, but could start to feel it when it reached the back of my hand.

It reached maximum sensation when it reached the back of my wrist. I could completely feel the difference, even when closing my eye.

**Thus, is the wrist denser in neurons than the finger tips?**

If this is true, since I know there is a type of torture that use needle to pin the victim's finger tip to cause serious pain, but if finger tips are less sensitive than the wist, shouldn't this torture should pin on the wrist to even cause more pain.

I have searched for the neuron density on our hand, but can't find a satisfactory answer, maybe I just search the wrong words.

Comment: Welcome to CogSci. Your question was put on hold. Please feel free to refine it though. We warmly welcome new users, but as a scientific community we try to keep up a certain level of scientificness. Obviously, the fingertips are among the most sensitive parts of the body, otherwise Braille readers would use their wrists to read right? To put it into other words, your question is based on anecdotal evidence and is hence based on an incorrect assumption. If you could improve your question given that the fingertips are among the most sensitive parts of the body, please feel free.

Comment: Thanks for correction and response. I have re-posted the thread to Biology Stack Exchange. You may close the thread if you want.

Comment: I've closed the question on Bio. Please edit the current question here. It's perfectly on topic here too once edited.